# Reference DLL - Allow previous versions at run time

Tags: c#, dll, reference, version

I have Specific Version set to False for a bunch of DLLs as references to a C# console project. I'm aware this is a compile time check.

So how can I allow previous versions of the DLLs during run time?

Thanks!

Comment: [AssemblyVersion] numbers give deep insight on how well a team works together.  If the major version number progressed beyond 3 or you've got pretty random build or revision numbers then you have a communication problem that version numbers can't fix.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN - Assembly Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx):

> The runtime distinguishes between regular and strong-named assemblies for the purposes of versioning. Version checking only occurs with strong-named assemblies.

If you *do* have a strong-named assembly, you can redirect the reference to it. See [MSDN - Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

In your case, you could use [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx). Here is an example:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
   var fullName = new AssemblyName(eventArgs.Name);
   // should check that the assembly is the one we support old versions for

   var wantedDLL = fullName.Name + ".dll";

   // locate the DLL here... your path will vary
   var found = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, wantedDLL));
   return found;
};
```

Alternately, if you know the exact old version number, you can load it with the [`Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) overload.

```
var fullName = new AssemblyName(eventArgs.Name)
               {
                   Version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0)
               };
return Assembly.Load(fullName);
```

You should also be careful with errors here. Throwing exceptions can result in weird behaviour, and if the assembly fails to be loaded, then the method will recurse infinitely resulting in `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: I've tried a redirect, however that doesn't appear to work as I'm looking for. Id have to say redirect 7.1.100 to 7.0.150, but what about the other machines that only have 7.1.100 - I only want to allow previous versions to work.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I think the only thing you can do is to find it manually using `AssemblyResolve`. I'll add an example.